# how to handle reappearing values with std::next_permutation

Tags: c++, permutation

I have a few vectors.
I want to find all permutations of each vector.
It works reasonably well, when the values are unique but if there are reappearing values it messes up.

I have the following vectors

```
vector<string> present = {"Schaukelpferd","Schaukelpferd","Puppe","Puppe"};
vector<string> children = {"Jan","Tim","Alex","Daniel"};
vector<int> houses = {4,5,5,5};
```

I am sorting the before using `next_permutation()`

```
sort(present.begin(),present.end());
sort(children.begin(),children.end());
sort(houses.begin(),houses.end());
do {
    present_perm.push_back(present);
} while (next_permutation(present.begin(), present.end()));
do {
    children_perm.push_back(children);
} while (next_permutation(children.begin(), children.end()));
do {
    houses_perm.push_back(houses);
} while (next_permutation(houses.begin(), houses.end()));
```

`children` works good, but present as well as houses doesn't work as expected

children returns `24` permutation, as expected, present returns only `6` and houses returns only `4`. I would expect all to return `24` because all vectors have `4` elements (`4! = 24`).

Comment: Check permutations of vectors of indices (`0`,`1`,...,`n-1`) instead?

Comment: I suspect the confusion comes from the meaning of **permutation**.  Mathematically speaking, "the set of all permutations" would not have duplicates.

Comment: Hhm, but what would I do if I need the duplicates. Because I need all result vectors to be the same size.

Comment: As the method uses no placement information it is only able to return the next higher permutation, otherwise it would get stuck. It would have no idea how many times to return 4555 before moving on to 5455, and again how many times to repeat.
If you really want the permutations and repetitions, you could give it a vector of pointers to the sorted content, and it would permute those addresses.

Comment: To avoid the extra look-up with your string case, you could give it a custom comparator that used the string addresses instead of doing the text compare. Another fix might be to pre-calculate the number of repetitions yourself: R = n! for each repeated n of a key, quickly discovered by scanning the sorted list, and simply have a wrapper class with a countdown that only moves the pattern forward every R calls.

Comment: pointer vectors worked and did exactly what i wanted. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the four integer values 4, 5, 5, 5. The four possible permutations are 4, 5, 5, 5 and 5, 4, 5, 5 and 5, 5, 4, 5 and 5, 5, 5, 4. That's it. The three 5s have the same value, so they cannot be distinguished from each other. The algorithm doesn't keep track of which of those values originally came before the other; they're the same. The same thing applies to `present`: there are three distinct values, not four.